# List characters (and their count) which meet a regex

Tags: sql, postgresql

This example lists the result of column `col`, which does not contain solely alphanumeric characters:

```
select col
from foo
where col ~ '[^a-zA-Z0-9]';
```

My aim is to list all the different characters which meet the regex with the count of their occurrence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
SELECT c.char[1], count(*) AS count
  FROM foo
 CROSS JOIN LATERAL regexp_matches(col, '[^a-zA-Z0-9]', 'g') AS c(char)
 GROUP BY c.char
```

see the test result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=d6aac284c27b509f637a70224be7029a).

Comment: that was easy ;)